# What are the privilege thresholds for the /review section?

Tags: support, review

At what reputation levels do:

- I finally see `/review` for the first time?
- I get "upgrades" to review? (And, what are these "upgrades"?)

I know not all the tabs are visible from the get-go, and because users don't just automagically see `/review` when they first register, but I can't seem to find the rep thresholds in `/privileges`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`/review` is accessible to all users, but does not appear in the top bar until [the 500 reputation milestone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).  While anybody can view recent reviews, the actual review queues are inaccessible until you gain the appropriate amount of reputation.  The reputation requirements for each queue correspond to the reputation required to perform most of the actions in that queue, with the exception of the first and late posts that both require 500.

For reference, the current reputation thresholds and their linked privileges are as follows:

- First Posts - 500 rep ([Access Review Queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues))
- Late Answers - 500 rep ([Access Review Queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues))
- Low Quality Posts - 2000 rep ([Edit Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))
- Suggested Edits - 2000 rep ([Edit Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))
- Close Votes - 3000 rep ([Close and Reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions))
- Reopen Votes - 3000 rep ([Close and Reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions))

Note that on beta sites and non-designed sites, the reputation requirements for privileges and the `/review` queue are lower.  Also, on per-site metas and Meta Stack Exchange, the First Posts and Late Answers queues don't exist, so the review icon won't show up in the top bar on those sites until you have 2000 reputation.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for and quite helpful. Thanks.

Comment: In case others don't see the edit, recently (2013 Jul, AFAICT) the thresholds were changed for First Posts and Late Answers from 125 to 500, and introduced (I think) to beta sites as 350.