# How to access Badge's Score?

Tags: support, badges

Once appeared to me a screen with my score for each badge. How to access this information again?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "badges with scores"?

Comment: Do you mean your [scores for tags](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/2702/ricardo-bevilaqua?tab=tags)

Comment: [Account badge page](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/2702/ricardo-bevilaqua?tab=badges)?

Comment: [Generic badge list](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/badges)?

Comment: For example, in "Civic Duty" badge how many times I've voted; in the "Strunk & White" badge how many times I edited posts, etc. Once appeared to me a screen with my score for each badge.I dont know how to access this information again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go to one of the review pages "/review/low-quality-posts/" and hover over the number near the stats

[image]

Comment: I thought the review queue is not visible until 2k rep?

Comment: @JoshMein I had no problem getting to it on Super user and I've got a whole 338 there, although I only have access to the First Posts and late answer queues

Comment: I cant see it here and have over 1k.

Comment: @JoshMein You get only to see the queues you can do something in. First posts and Late answers don't require much rep.

Comment: Again I cant see the review queue on meta and I have over 1k rep. I assume the rep requirements must be different on other sites then.

Comment: @JoshMein You can see the review queue by typing the URL in the address bar, only then it will tell you that you need at least 2k rep to review on meta. You can however still hover over the number and see the badge progress.

Comment: @Antony I knew you could do that. I was just confused on how the OP would have known the page existed if he cant access it without knowing the link, but I think the rep requirements might be different depending on the site.

Comment: @JoshMein Meta doesn't have First Posts or Late Answers so you'll need at least 2K, but every where else it's 125 [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121706/148672)